# Who is a zombie amongst the 3 and why?

Tags: riddle, visual, lateral-thinking

Here is a picture of $3$ people eating food. 
Can you spot who is a zombie amongst them? and why?

[image]

Taken From :- **7-Second Riddles**

Comment: Can someone explain the downvotes?

Comment: This is a low-quality "riddle" taken from another source; many intentional "zombie characteristics" are given to the people drawn, and we're basically required to guess which of them was the intended one and which were distractions.

Comment: I think it's a funny riddle. Not too much high-quality, as mentioned, but it's funny non the less. You did everything right, and mentioned the source of it. And sometimes it's nice to find a simple puzzle in this ocean of hard questions... +1 for your boldness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the most likely candidate would be

> The person on the left

Because

> Flies are mainly attracted to decaying organic filth such as rotting meat which I would assume is most like what a zombie would eat, rather than salad or eggs and toast. There is also some semblance of rigor mortis evident in this person's disposition.

Comment: There was me thinking it was #2 because a zombie probably lacks the coordination to do up a necktie...!

Comment: I though it was #3... The bread looked rotten at my first glimpse. Not toasted... Ops!